# External js for magento 2 backend not loaded

Tags: magento-2.1, javascript, adminhtml, jquery, requirejs

I create the external js for magento 2 backend like this:

`Namespace/Module/view/adminhtml/requirejs-config.js`:

```
 var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            regionsForm: 'Namespace_Module/js/regions-form'
        }
    }
};
```

in `Namespace/Module/view/adminhtml/web/js/regions-form.js`

```
    define([
        'jquery',
        'underscore',
        'mage/url',
        'jquery/ui'
        ], function ($, _,urlBuilder) {
        'use strict';
        $(function() { 
           console.log('a'); 
        });
    });
```

i already delete pub/static and ran setup:upgrade & static:content, but when i inspect element in my browser i cant find my js file, but in pub/static my file is already there.

**Edit:**
I ran deploy command `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: Have you run  deploy command php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: @Rakesh yes i already did that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that we didn't call the custom script. So, we can call it via template or the head. You can try two cases:

1) We can add directly on the head.

*app/code/Namespace/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/default.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="Namespace_Module::js/regions-form.js"/>
    </head>
    <body/>
</page>
```

In this case, remember to change `define` to `require` in the custom script.

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'mage/url',
    'jquery/ui'
], function ($, _,urlBuilder) {
    'use strict';
    console.log('Here');
    return 1;
});
```

2) We can call it via template:

*app/code/Company/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/test.phtml*

```
<script>
    require(["regionsForm"], function($form){
        //Your code here
    })
</script>
```

Comment: i got this error `define is not a function at regions-form.js:1`

Comment: You add your script on the head or via template?

Comment: i added it via template

Comment: Okay! Let me check again.

Comment: okay, is it requirejs-config.js that caused the problem?

Comment: sorry my mistake i add it  add directly on the head, then i got that error

Comment: So, you added the custom js file directly on the head?

Comment: yes from default.xml, then i got that error

Comment: the problem is my js is loaded before require.js

Comment: If adding on the head,  remember to change `define` to `require` in the custom script. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Run commands in this sequence can help you:

`sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo chmod -R 777 var
sudo chmod -R 777 pub
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
sudo php bin/magento cache:flush
sudo php bin/magento cache:clean
sudo chmod -R 777 var
sudo chmod -R 777 pub`

it might work if there is any permission related issue.

Comment: done that, still not working, i think it's not permission because the file is already exist in pub/static

Comment: can we use `require` in regions-form.js instead of `define`

Comment: still not working

Comment: [see here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/requirejs_concept.html) if you are missing something OR you need to add `regionsForm` in regions-form.js and if it is not working add your module js file in admin layout `default.xml` file.